# Sending an Email Notification from Google Sites

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sites

I've been trying to set up an email notification for when I create a new announcement in my google site. I used a base code I found online but it isn't working for me. Here it is:

```
function myFunction() {

var url_of_announcements_page = "https://sites.google.com/announcements-page-link"; 
var who_to_email = "name@company.com" 

function emailAnnouncements(){
  var page = SitesApp.getPageByUrl(url_of_announcements_page); 
  if(page.getPageType() == SitesApp.PageType.ANNOUNCEMENTS_PAGE){ 

    var announcements = page.getAnnouncements({ start: 0,
                                               max: 10,
                                               includeDrafts: false,
                                               includeDeleted: false});
    announcements.reverse();                                    
    for(var i in announcements) { 
      var ann = announcements[i]; 
      var updated = ann.getLastUpdated().getTime(); 
      if (updated > ScriptProperties.getProperty('last-update')){ 
        var options = {}; 

        options.htmlBody = Utilities.formatString("<h1><a href='%s'>%s</a></h1>%s", ann.getUrl(), ann.getTitle(), ann.getHtmlContent());

        MailApp.sendEmail(who_to_email, "Announcement "+ann.getTitle(), ann.getTextContent()+"\n\n"+ann.getUrl(), options);

        ScriptProperties.setProperty('last-update',updated);
      }
    }
  }
}

function setup(){
  ScriptProperties.setProperty('last-update',new Date().getTime());
}
}
```

The code seems to run with out any error message appearing. However, I do not receive the emails on the account I write in the code. I have given full permission so that the script can send the email from my account. It just doesn't seem to fulfil the task needed.

The google site I am using to write the announcements is still private and only I can see it, does that play a role in this code not working?

If you see any mistakes or have any idea what the issue is I would be happy to know.

Comment: Can you tell us what kind of error you got, or what you're expect from this code that is not working ?

Comment: The code seems to run with out any error message appearing. However, I do not receive the emails on the account I write in the code. I have given full permission so that the script can send the email from my account. It just doesn't seem to fulfil the task needed.

Comment: Dummy question: Do you have change the url_of_announcements_page and who_to_email variable from your code found online ?

Comment: Yes dw I change them :) I use the link from my site and a dummy email account I made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have written both the functions under `myFunction`. You need to write it separately. Also `ScriptProperties` **API is deprecated**, use `PropertiesService`. Refer the below code. Hope this helps!

```
var url_of_announcements_page = "https://sites.google.com/announcements-page-link"; 
var who_to_email = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();

function emailAnnouncements(){
  var page = SitesApp.getPageByUrl(url_of_announcements_page); 
  if(page.getPageType() == SitesApp.PageType.ANNOUNCEMENTS_PAGE){ 

    var announcements = page.getAnnouncements({ start: 0,
                                               max: 10,
                                               includeDrafts: false,
                                               includeDeleted: false});
    announcements.reverse();                                    
    for(var i in announcements) { 
      var ann = announcements[i]; 
      var updated = ann.getLastUpdated().getTime(); 
      if (updated > PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty("last-update")){ 
        var options = {}; 

        options.htmlBody = Utilities.formatString("<h1><a href='%s'>%s</a></h1>%s", ann.getUrl(), ann.getTitle(), ann.getHtmlContent());

        MailApp.sendEmail(who_to_email, "Announcement "+ann.getTitle(), ann.getTextContent()+"\n\n"+ann.getUrl(), options);

        PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty('last-update',updated);
      }
    }
  }
}

function setup(){
 PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty('last-update',new Date().getTime());
}
```